# Is there a non-free group $G$ whose subgroups are all freely decomposable?

Tags: gr.group-theory, free-groups

Suppose that $G$ is a group such that every subgroup $H \subseteq G$ (including $G$ itself) is either free or a non-trivial free product, i.e. $H = H_1 * H_2$ with $H_1, H_2$ both non-trivial. Is there an example of such a $G$ which is not free?

If $G$ is finitely generated then Grushko's theorem implies $G$ must be free, but the infinitely-generated case seems likely to have a non-free example.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, there's an example.

Kurosh proved that the group $G$ with presentation
$$\langle (a_n)_{n\ge 0},(b_n)_{n\ge 1}\mid a_nb_na_n^{-1}b_n^{-1}=a_{n-1},\;\forall n\ge 1\rangle$$

has the following properties: $G$ is torsion-free, isomorphic to $G\ast\mathbf{Z}$, all freely indecomposable subgroups of $G$ are cyclic, but $G$ is not free (it's easily checked not to be residually nilpotent: the intersection of the lower central series contains all $a_n$).

Reference: A. Kurosch. Zum Zerlegungsproblem der Theorie der freien Produkte. Mat. Sbornik 2 (44): 5, 995–1001, 1937.

---

[Added] Context:

Kurosh asked in 1934 (Math Ann.) the (free) **Zerlegungsproblem**: *does every group have a free product decomposition into freely indecomposable factor?*

In the same 1934 paper he proved that if the answer is positive for a given group, then all such decompositions are isomorphic. This was improved by Baer and Levi (Comp. Math. 1936): on an arbitrary group, any two free product decompositions (with possibly decomposable factors) have a common refinement (in a suitable sense). Then in 1937 (Mat. Sbornik) Kurosh found the above example providing in general a negative solution to the Zerlegungsproblem. Later, Grushko (Mat. Sbornik 1940) and then independently B.H. Neumann (J. LMS 1943) proved that the Zerlegungsproblem has a positive answer for finitely generated groups, showing that the generating rank is additive (and not only sub-additive) under free products.

---

Added remark: there's an embedding of the countable group $G$ into the 3-generator group with 1-relator presentation
$$\Gamma=\langle a,x,y\mid a={^x}\!a\;^y\!a\rangle\qquad (\text{where } {^x}\!a\;^y\!a=xax^{-1}yay^{-1}),$$
given by $a_n\mapsto x^{-n}ax^{n}$, $b_n\mapsto x^{-n}yx^{n}$. I don't know if this 1-relator group has ever been studied specifically.

More precisely, $\Gamma$ is the ascending HNN-extension of $G$ associated with the injective endomorphism $i$ given by $a_n\mapsto a_{n+1}$, $b_n\mapsto b_{n+1}$ (note that $G=i(G)\ast\langle b_0\rangle$).

Comment: I don't know whether your one-relator group has been "explicitly studied", but it's a very easy group to describe: it is the fundamental group of the space obtained from the 3-holed sphere with boundary components $a,b,c$ by gluing $b$ and $c$ to $a$. In particular, it's certainly hyperbolic, and has many nice properties.

Comment: How do you see that $\langle (a_i)_{n\geq 0},(b_i)_{n\geq 1},(c_i)_{n\geq 1},(d_i)_{n\geq 1}\mid \left[a_n,b_n\right]\left[c_n,d_n\right]=a_{n-1},\forall n\geq 1\rangle$ is not isomorphic to Kurosh's group?

Comment: @seldomseen I made no such claim (I didn't mention this group). Feel free to post a question if the answer is not immediate.

Comment: That was a question. And nothing in the question implies that you made such a claim.

Comment: @seldomseen After reading "How do you see that" my first reaction was to check where I did such a claim.

Comment: The 'you' in 'how do you see that' is the generic you, and does not mean you, Y.C., but some unspecified person, like 'one' does. It is perfectly normal in colloquial English. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @seldomseen sure, I understood this retrospectively. Another thing: if I'm asked "How do you see that X is true", I assume that X is known (for some reason) to be true, so naturally wonders why you know it's true. Anyway, this might be a natural follow-up question.

Comment: You can also see that Kurosh's group is not free by observing that $G$ is freely indecomposable relative to $a_0$, whereas any infinitely generated free group is freely decomposable relative to any element.

Comment: @seldomseen What does "$G$ freely decomposable with respect to $g$" mean?

Comment: Has a (nontrivial) free product decomposition with $g$ conjugate into one of the factors.